How to use ThreadPoolExecutor concurrently with infinite loops
I'm developing a application to fetch data from different servers that are bound to each other.
Basically, each server has a major region, like America or Asia, and sub regions, like North America, Brazil. Each server has it's own bounded sub regions.
Major regions and sub regions don't share methods, so i wanted to run then on parallel.
My basic approach was to create a thread for each region with executor.map(), then inside of each new thread create the threads for the subdivisions.
All the threads are supposed to run indefinitely and independently.
The code is like this:
def main_region_fetching(region_list):
    cur_region = next(iter(region_list.keys()))
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(
            max_workers=len(region_list["cur_region"])
        ) as executor:
            for region in region_list[cur_region]:
                executor.submit(sub_region_fetching, region)

    # The main region code should continue in here, but it doesn't reach.

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(regions)) as executor:
    executor.map(main_region_fetching, regions)

The sub_region_fetching blocks the continuation of the main thread. Does it waits for the finalization of the thread? Can i make it run the thread without blocking the main? Since it's supposed to run indefinitely.
There is any other better alternative? Like using async for example.

From the Python documentation:

All threads enqueued to ThreadPoolExecutor will be joined before the
interpreter can exit. Note that the exit handler which does this is
executed before any exit handlers added using atexit. This means
exceptions in the main thread must be caught and handled in order to
signal threads to exit gracefully. For this reason, it is recommended
that ThreadPoolExecutor not be used for long-running tasks.

For an endless loop, you can do something like this:
import threading
from time import sleep

lock = threading.Lock()
resultdict = {}



def thread_function(name):
    for i in range(100):
        resultdict.setdefault(name, []).append(i)
        sleep(1)


for r in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(r,))
    t.start()

print(resultdict)
sleep(5)
try:
    lock.acquire()  # if you want to access the data without messing it up
    resultdict[0].append(1000)
finally:
    lock.release()


By using an Executor in a with block, you are telling that the executor must be done by the end of that with block.
As your submitted tasks do not return, execution of your main thread will stall at the end of the with block.
The problem at hand would allow you to even use simple threading.Threads, instead of a thread pool executor: the later is good for re-using the same threads in new functions over and over again. However, using an executor can take care of some boiler plate part to start and send data to functions running in other threads, and may be a useful pattern even when you are not taking advantage of re-using the threads.
All you have to do is know that your code have to either live within the with block for the executor - (you can make a function call from there so that you don't have to actually write complicated logic inside the with  body) - or just use a try - finally block to start and end the Executor itself.
Given your snippet, the simplest change for things to work is:
def main_region_fetching(region_list):
    cur_region = next(iter(region_list.keys()))
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(
            max_workers=len(region_list["cur_region"]) + 1  # adding  1 thread for the main region
        ) as executor:
            for region in region_list[cur_region]:
                executor.submit(sub_region_fetching, region)

            # The main region code continues here, inside the `with` block

            executor.map(main_region_fetching, regions)  



